# How can I centralize this jquery styling colors into css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code in a number of HTML files:

```
$("table.altRow tr:odd").css("background-color", "#eeecec");
$("table.altRow tr:even").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

How can I change this so the colors are defined in one place so if I want to change it I only need to change it once (instead of on every page).  One requirement i have is that i sometime delete rows (and then call this code again to "reset" the alt row colors .  I need that to continue to work

(NOTE: that i am doing this dynamically so I can't get rid of this jquery code and fully replace with css).

For example, i often delete rows and then run the code above to keep alternate row data accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, combining my answer with others' answers to hopefully address the complete solution:

**1)** Add the rules to an [external css stylesheet](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php) (e.g. make a file called `style.css` with the following content:)

```
.lowlight { 
background-color: #eeecec;
}

.highlight { 
background-color: #fff;
}
```

**2)** To link to the stylesheet, this needs to be in the `<head>` of your HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your/style.css" />
```

**3)** And finally, to assign styles to the relevant table rows:

```
$("table.altRow tr:even").addClass("lowlight");
```

You may need to remove the old class as well, e.g.

```
$("table.altRow tr:even").addClass("lowlight").removeClass("highlight");
```

Comment: I am not trying to get rid of the jquery driven css.  I am just trying to move the color definition so they are centralized

Comment: Odd/Even pseudo-selectors don't exist in CSS. Perhaps `tr:nth-child(even)`

Answer (score 1):

Use classes like,

```
.color1 { background-color : #eeecec; }
.color2 { background-color : #ffffff; }
```

And in JS use `.addClass()`,

```
   $("table.altRow tr:odd").addClass("color1");
   $("table.altRow tr:even").addClass("color2");
```

The advantage behind this is, you can remove the colours later if you don't want it, by using `.removeClass()`.

Comment: The issue is now if i delete rows it breaks the alternative row coloring (where before it worked)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a generic JS file which gets loaded before every other JS file and declare some unique globally-scoped vars that you should avoid over-writing in sub-subsequent JS files:

**autoload.js**

```
var glob_unique_odd_tr = '#eeecec';
var glob_unique_even_tr = '#ffffff';
```

**yourjsfile.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table.altRow tr:odd").css("background-color", glob_unique_odd_tr );
    $("table.altRow tr:even").css("background-color", glob_unique_even_tr );
});
```

**Your HTML files JS load order from now on**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="autoload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourjsfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Definitely workable, but wouldn't it be better practice to separate formatting out from the js and into CSS's presentation layer? That's what CSS is for

Comment: It depends on what OP wants to do with the declaration. If I am not mistaken then OP might be limited to jQuery UI's `.switchClass()` if they want to animate a CSS class-driven change.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the variable/constant in PHP and generate a PHP CSS file (ie.: `myCSS.php`)

Here is an example:

**PHP / CSS (single file)**

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 
    $main_color = "#00bfff"; #sky light blue
    $secondary_color = "#FFF"; #white
?>
```

```
html{
    background-color:#DDD;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: <?php echo $main_color;?>;
}

div {
    border-color: <?php echo $main_color;?>;
}

altRow tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: <?php echo $secondary_color;?>;
}
```

You get the file within your HTML file like any regular CSS file.